# Flash messages in EJS

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

```
    //This is my route.js
        router.post('/restful', function(req, res){
            var options = {
                uri : 'http://192.168.1.6:8080/RestTGRP/TGRP/checkAPI',
                method : 'post'
            }; 
            var responseFromClient = '';
            request(options, function (error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    responseFromClient = body;
                }
                else {
                    responseFromClient = 'Not Found';
                }
                console.log(responseFromClient);
                //res.json(resss);
                req.flash('response_msg', responseFromClient);


                if(responseFromClient !='Not Found'){
                  res.redirect('/users/restful');
                }
                else{
                  res.redirect('/users/restful');
                }
            });
         });


        //in view.handlebars

        {{#if response_msg}}
                 <div class="alert alert-danger">{{response_msg}}</div>
                 {{/if}}
```

I am creating a method which is calling a restful webservice and I am trying to print their response as "response_msg".

Previously I was using handlebars, so I was able to print it.

Now I am using my view.engine as `EJS`, but I am not been able to print it.

How can we do it?

Answer (score 0):

This made the code worked

0){ %>

<%= response_msg %>